# How to pair non-generic custom URLs in a URL Shortener?

Tags: php, url-shortener

Our PHP web app has an integrated URL shortener with URL-Slug Customisation.

Users can already edit the example.com/**somerandomstring** part of their generated URLs into f.e. example.com/**chosenstring**.

However now we want to add complete custom URLs, meaning that instead of only customising the path (somerandomstring), we want them to be able to add their own, owned domains.
In other words they should be able to turn **example.com/somerandomstring** into **theirurl.com/chosenstring**

What are the necessary steps to consider here? Is there a trick to automise this effectively with PHP or another related language? Which DNS records will need to be set exactly?

Comment: Ae you the owner of the client domains?
You would have to access the DNS of `theirurl.com` to do this.
In general you cant rewrite the domain if you are not owning it. Also, changing DNS settings can take up to 48h our till its distributed, so you dont just do that on the fly.

Comment: No, the domains would technically still be owned by the client.
I know that there are DNS difficulties to be solved here, but bit.ly and other URL shortening services manage to do this. 
Here's an example from bit.ly where they explain how their service uses this feature: https://bitly.com/pages/features/branded-links

Comment: Or is the solution actually this simple and bit.ly etc. need to own these domains in order to be able to do this?

Comment: Or can it be done by simply setting an A record on theirurl.com's server that points to my server ip?